# ListView gets an unexpected error

Tags: android, listview

I have a problem with a ListView and i constantly get an unexpected error :(
when i am trying to run it on my SamsungGalaxy s4 mini i get an error and it crashes and after several seconds it turns off. what am i doing wrong?
this is my code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {

private ListView listview01;
private TextView TextView01;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    Student students_data[] = new Student[]
            {
                    new Student("Nikos", "Apostolakis", "2012", "03112023"),
                    new Student("Stavros", "Birbilis", "2012", "03112116")
            };


    StudentAdapter adapter = new StudentAdapter(this, R.layout.studentitemlayout, students_data);
    listview01 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    TextView01 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.HelloWorld);
    TextView01.setText("BreakPointReached!");


    listview01.setAdapter(adapter);


}
```

}

and my classes are

```
public class Student {

public String  FirstName;
public String  LastName;
public String  JoinedYear;
public int     JoinedRank;

public Student() {
    super();
}

public Student(String FirstName , String LastName , String JoinedYear, String JoinedRank){
    this.FirstName  = FirstName;
    this.LastName   = LastName;
    this.JoinedYear = JoinedYear;
    this.JoinedRank = Integer.parseInt(JoinedRank);
}
```

}

and

```
public class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
Student data[] = null;

public StudentAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Student[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
     StudentHolder holder = null;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new StudentHolder();
        holder.FirstName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.FirstName);
        holder.LastName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.LastName);
        holder.JoinedYear = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.JoinedYear);
        holder.JoinedRank = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.JoinedRank);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (StudentHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Student student = data[position];
    holder.FirstName.setText(student.FirstName);
    holder.LastName.setText(student.LastName);
    holder.JoinedYear.setText(student.JoinedYear);
    holder.JoinedRank.setText(student.JoinedRank);

    return row;
}

static class StudentHolder {
    TextView FirstName;
    TextView LastName;
    TextView JoinedYear;
    TextView JoinedRank;
}
```

}

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/FirstName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="22dp"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LastName"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/JoinedYear"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/JoinedRank"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".FirstActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HelloWorld"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="HelloWorld"/>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ListView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>
```

Comment: 12-16 16:13:11.445  16128-16128/app.nikos.apostolakis.studentsresults.studentsresults E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2f7c57
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1057)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4183)

Comment: this line: `holder.JoinedRank.setText(student.JoinedRank);`. read the doc for that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all resources exists in their corresponding layout XMLs.

**R.id.FirstName**

**R.id.LastName**

**R.id.JoinedYear**

**R.id.JoinedRank**

**R.id.HelloWorld**

Edit:

You have set the text of a text view from Integer.

Replace

```
holder.JoinedRank.setText(student.JoinedRank);
```

with this

```
holder.JoinedRank.setText(student.JoinedRank+"");
```

Good Luck. :)

Comment: unrelated. the logcat does not point to a missing id, but to a missing string.

Comment: in Android Studio: File -> Invalidate caches/Restart -> Just restart

Comment: thanks all of you guys.. i had set JoinedRank as an integer and i should convert it to String. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Student student = data[position];
holder.FirstName.setText(student.FirstName);
holder.LastName.setText(student.LastName);
holder.JoinedYear.setText(student.JoinedYear);
holder.JoinedRank.setText(student.JoinedRank);
```

I suppose your student.JoinedRank is an integer. Which invokes the `setText(int resId)` method and that leads to the Exception, as there will not be a string constant in the `R` class with value 2010 or the like.

Change the line to

```
holder.JoinedRank.setText("" + student.JoinedRank);
```

and it should work.